# Prime Factor Encoding

Tags: code-golf, primes, factoring, encoding

## How the encoding works

Given a list of bits:

- Hold a prime (starting with `2`)
- Have a list
- For each bit in the input

  - If it's the same as the previous bit, add the prime you're holding to the list
  - If it's different, hold the next prime and add that to the list
- Return the product of all the numbers in your list
- For the first bit, assume the previous bit was `0`

> Note: these steps are for illustration purposes only, you are not required to follow them.

## Examples

```
Input: 001
hold 2

0:         add 2 to the list
0:         add 2 to the list
1: hold 3, add 3 to the list

list: 2,2,3
Output: 12
```

---

```
Input: 1101
hold 2

1: hold 3, add 3 to the list
1:         add 3 to the list
0: hold 5, add 5 to the list
1: hold 7, add 7 to the list

list: 3,3,5,7
Output: 315
```

#### Some more examples:

```
000000000 -> 512
111111111 -> 19683
010101010 -> 223092870
101010101 -> 3234846615
011101101 -> 1891890
000101101010010000 -> 3847834029582062520
```

## Challenge

Write an encoder **and** a decoder for this encoding method.

(The decoder reverses the process of the encoder).

## Input / Output

- The encoder can take input in [any reasonable format](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)
- The encoder must output either an integer or a string
- The decoder must take input in the same format that the encoder outputs
- The decoder must output the same format that the encoder takes as input

In other words `decoder( encoder( input ) ) === input`

#### Notes

- The decoder may assume that its input is decodable
- Your answer only has to deal with integers that your language can natively support without using (`long`, `bigInt`, etc.), be reasonable, if you language only supports ints up to 1, maybe reconsider posting an answer

## Scoring

Your score is the sum of the lengths in bytes of the encoder and decoder.

If you need to import a module, the import can be counted only once provided that your encoder and decoder can coexist in the same file and be reused (like functions).

[Default loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest score for every language wins.

Comment: Is that last example mandatory, or can we limit the output to up to 64 bits (2^63-1 / 9223372036854775808)?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen No, your answer only has to work for integers that your language can handle.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen *handle natively without libraries of bigints, i'll clarify

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 13 bytes

### Encoder, 8 bytes

```
0ì¥ĀηOØP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9TVvnf4PCaQ0uPNJzb7n94RsD/SqXD@xV07RQO71fS@W9gYMhlaAgkDGAAyIUCLgNDKOSCMcDqgBSEB0IgAgA)

**Explanation**

```
0ì          # prepend 0 to input
  ¥         # calculate deltas
   Ā        # truthify each
    η       # calculate prefixes
     O      # sum each
      Ø     # get the prime at that index
       P    # product
```

### Decoder, 5 bytes

```
Ò.ØÉJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcm7DYAgEADQnimItRruw3E0DuAWmriCCYkL2Fq5DcUNhli94oW47XC06yzNntleu9dWBqt@WrzVYWyAjiC62IUsSg6RQkZNwRESK4v8rZRAGLFHzKrKqBw@)

**Explanation**

```
Ò       # get prime factors of input
 .Ø     # get their indices among the primes
   É    # check for oddness
    J   # join
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

#### Encoder (10 bytes):

```
0;IA+\‘ÆNP
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/A2tNRO@ZRw4zDbX4B////jzbQAUFDMDaEswzgJBDGAgA)**

#### Decoder (7 bytes):

```
ÆEĖŒṙḂ¬
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//w4ZFxJbFkuG5meG4gsKs////Mzg0NzgzNDAyOTU4MjA2MjUyMA)**

#### How?

Encoder:

```
0;IA+\‘ÆNP - Link: list of integers (1s and 0s)  e.g. [1,1,1,1,0]
0;         - prepend a zero                           [0,1,1,1,1,0]
  I        - incremental differences                  [1,0,0,0,-1]
   A       - absolute values                          [1,0,0,0,1]
    +\     - cumulative reduce with addition          [1,1,1,1,2]
      ‘    - increment each of the results            [2,2,2,2,3]
       ÆN  - get the nth prime for each result        [3,3,3,3,5]
         P - product of the list                      405
```

Decoder:

```
ÆEĖŒṙḂ¬ - Link: integer         e.g. 405
ÆE      - prime exponent array       [0,4,1] (representing 2^0*3^4*5^1)
  Ė     - enumerate                  [[1,0],[2,4],[3,1]]
   Œṙ   - run-length decode          [2,2,2,2,3]
     Ḃ  - bit (mod 2)                [0,0,0,0,1]
      ¬ - logical NOT                [1,1,1,1,0]
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 130 bytes

**I/O:** array of bits ↔  integer

### Encoder, 71 bytes

```js
a=>a.map(p=k=>r*=(g=i=>n%--i?g(i):i<2?n:g(++n))(n+=p^(p=k)),r=1,n=2)&&r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc7PCoJAEAbwu0/hJdnJ9e9RGj35FFGwmSxrNrus0utvBSa1GB8zh@HHxwziIabOKjMnpK@9a9EJrEV6F4YZvGFt98gkKqxplySqkUxBpQ5lQ5VkcUwAjGI05zcG4BYLTlhCFFnXaZr02Kejlqxlx5x7OQEEnim4lw2Tv@4/s9njqT89xSJWE2RZOGsdXpQMNv//8st8dr5@454)

### Decoder, 59 bytes

```js
D=(n,k=2,x=b=0)=>k>n?[]:n%k?D(n,k+1,1):[b^=x,...D(n/k,k,0)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYzLCsIwFAX3/oeQ4DXm0cakcNtN/6JUaGsRTUnEivTvY1xK4KxmmPMYPsM6ve7P99GH6xxji8SDQwkbjsgp1q72TddXfu@a9qcOAgStuvGCGzDGEjs5cMBpH6fg17DMbAk30pJSSEp3/0xYbVRGpVTcSnPmmVFSFabQWpT5lbFpKYlf)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>234</s> <s>193</s> 174 bytes

### Encoder, <s>116</s> <s>101</s> 97 bytes:

Uses [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson's_theorem).

```python
i=input()
P=n=x=r=1
while i:
 P*=n*n;n+=1
 if P%n:t=(i+[x]).index(x);i=i[t:];r*=n**t;x^=1
print r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYzBCsIwEETv@Yq9CEkq0nhM2H/IPcSTlS7IGsJK49fHiIgUhmHeMEx5yfrgc@@ExOUp2qiIjA0rOrWtdF@AvIJokS0HnkYLdIN4YC@oaUotmxPxdWm6mTBOkvgc6mduJbTL2JdKLFB7T/MRvnI/d3uc9@GP@Q0)

### Decoder, <s>118</s> <s>92</s> 77 bytes:

```python
i=input()
r=[]
n=x=1
while~-i:
 n+=1;x^=i%n<1
 while i%n<1:r+=x,;i/=n
print r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcnBCoMwDADQe76iF2GiY2tWbabLl4jeBAMjltKxetmvd@Dx8cKRtl2xFGHR8EmXGiJPMyhntvDd5L3@rjKA0YbtmBeWSl8WzDnmxBAbzu0oN1YIUTSZWEpHD297h4jkuycROSR3/wM)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 10, 209 bytes

### Encoder, 124 bytes

```java
s->{long p=48,P=2,r=1,n,i;for(int c:s.getBytes()){if(p!=(p=c))for(n=0;n<2;)for(n=++P,i=2;i<n;n=n%i++<1?0:n);r*=P;}return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##jY/BasMwEETv@YptoCDVjrFCDyWyWui9wZBj6UFV5KDUWRtJDgTjb3fl2OmtxKsVaLWPYeYoz3J13P/0qpTOwYc02C4ADHptC6k0bIcRoKzwAIrsvDXh4SgPv124oZ2X3ijYAoKA3q1e2ytci@eXOBfr2AoWY2x4UVkSdEFtXHLQ/v3itSOUtqYg9YMgtVCUDgyKlGO25tMQRXlsxJqbDDkKfDRRlLG3dIOU2yeR885q31gEy7uej47q5rsMjiZj58rs4RSCTe4/v0DSMdXu4rw@JVXjkzqsfIkEE0WWacqW9Jrxf4axGVB6qxlyU93XZNO5r3lD5/gM2EgP/We4W3T9Lw)

**Explanation:**

```java
s->{                // Method with String parameter and long return-type
  long p=48,        //  Previous character, starting at '0'
       P=2,         //  Current prime, starting at 2
       r=1,         //  Result, starting at 1
       n,i;         //  Temp-integers
  for(int c:s.getBytes()){
                    //  Loop over the digits of the input-String as bytes
    if(p!=(p=c))    //   If the current and previous digits are different
      for(n=0;      //    Reset `n` to 0
          n<2;)     //    And loop as long as `n` is still 0 or 1
        for(n=++P,  //     Increase `P` by 1 first with `++P`, and set `n` to this new `P`
            i=2;i<n;n=n%i++<1?0:n);
                    //     Check of the current `n` is a prime
                    //     If it remains the same it's a prime, if it becomes 0 or 1 not
    r*=P;}          //   Multiply the result by the current prime `P`
  return r;}        //  Return the result
```

### Decoder, 85 bytes

```java
n->{var r="";for(long P=2,f=0,i=1;++i<=n;)for(;n%i<1;n/=P=i)r+=i!=P?f^=1:f;return r;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY5ha4MwEIa/91fcCgPF1plEbVya7Q9sRdjHsUFmdaSzZ4lRGMXf7tLZfRzCHcfdvXfvc1C9Wh/2X2NRq7aFZ6XxvADQaEtTqaKE3aUFeLFG4ycUXt24gr5w08Gli9YqqwvYAYKEEdcP514ZMHK5FFVjpoNc0pWWZFXJSASB3koU/mUp8FZvicA7mUvtm0DqG5k/Vu@S3FfClLYzCEYMo5isTt1H7ayujn2j93B0xN5E9/oGyr/ifre2PIZNZ8OTW9kaPQwLj9An/xf9XwUjyZwkmf9CspSzORGlLMoo30SzTJTFPE7TeTTG4w1ncUSzhNMopQn9ez4shvEH)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{                // Method with long parameter and String return-type
  var r="";         //  Result-String, starting empty
  for(long P=2,     //  Current prime, starting at 2
      f=0,          //  Flag integer, starting at 0
      i=1;++i<=n;)  //  Loop `i` in the range [2,`n`]
    for(;n%i<1;     //   Inner loop over the prime factors of `n`
        n/=P=i)     //     After every iteration: divide `n` by `i`,
                    //     and set `P` to `i` at the same time
      r+=i!=P?      //    If `i` and `P` are not the same
          f^=1      //     Append the opposite of the flag `f` (0→1; 1→0)
         :          //    Else:
          f;        //     Append the flag `f`
  return r;}        //  Return the result
```

Comment: You can save 2 bytes by changing `long` to `int`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Codepage)

#### Encoder, 11 bytes

```
Πmo!İp→∫Ẋ≠Θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9yC3HzFIxsKHrVNetSx@uGurkedC87N@P//f7ShDgQaxAIA)

#### Decoder, 7 bytes

```
mȯ¬%2ṗp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P/fE@kNrVI0e7pxe8P//fxMDUwA)

#### How they work

Encoder:

```
Πmo!İp→∫Ẋ≠Θ – Full program. Takes input from the first CLA, outputs to STDOUT.
          Θ – Prepend a default element (0 in this case).
        Ẋ≠  – Map over pairs of adjacent elements with ≠ (not equals). In Husk,
              some operators return other useful things than just boolean values.
              Here, ≠ returns the absolute difference between its two arguments.
       ∫    – Cumulative sums.
 mo         – Map the following function over the list of sums:
    İp        – Yield the infinite list of primes.
   !  →       – And index into it with the current sum incremented.
Π           – Take the product.
```

Decoder:

```
mȯ¬%2ṗp – Full program.
      p – Prime factorization.
mȯ      – Map the following function over the list of factors:
     ṗ    – Retrieve the index in  the list of primes.
   %2     – Modulo 2.
  ¬       – Logical NOT.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>180</s> 184 bytes

- Added four bytes so that output formats match.

## 102 bytes -- Encoder

```c
p,r,i,m;e(char*_){for(m=0,p=1,i=2;*_;m=*_++-48,p*=i)if(*_-48-m)for(i++,r=2;r<i;i%r++||(r=2,i++));i=p;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7PboMwDMbvfYqMiSomRiOoh7YhvfAKPU5CFX86H8KilJ0oz85MB3MO9mf/Psd1eq/refYYkNCZVtZft5BUMHbfQTqbobcayeYmqYyzSaVUejiiTywBdTKpWKUOFpiUwsBgKMhQHJR6PiVr5D6AIevNNDey3DaXcb7gyvEPuSkv2ngGeWcZ@0KDT8N@z9ibY8oD@p9huUw6dTgClh/WL5eZaffetB31rbjKxxBAjMIH6odORvHpIc5nEZ8aUaQXEaFgAEX74sCIRv6Xm@Wzj1hNO3ejXsJ4lVGW6Qg4a70W2RZre42/mV7fqhbTyzfNvw)

## 82 bytes -- Decoder

```c
d(C){for(m=C%2,r=2+m,p=2;C>1;p++)if(C%p<1)p-r&&(m=!m,r=p),putchar(m+48),C/=p,p=1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5NboMwEIX3OYVLReTBg4pRFkmMs@EKWVZCET@pF6Yjh64IZ6dDCh0vPG/8veep03tdz4QBHXrTyvrrFpIKxu47SG8zJKvR2dwklfE2qZRKD0ekxDpwnUwqVqmHBXZKYWAwFM64OCj1fErWyHMA4yyZaW5kuSWXcb7gyvMPuSkv2hCDnFnGVGigNOz3jL15pgiQfoZlM@nV4QhYflhaNuPI3XvTdq5vxVU@hgBiFBRcP3Qyik8PcT6L@NSIIr2ICAUDKNoXB0Y08r/dLJ99xGra@ZvrJYxXGWWZjoBvrdcm22odr/X3ptezqsX08k3zLw)

Comment: @AsoneTuhid Sorry, misread.

Comment: @AsoneTuhid Now added a decoder. Hopefully compliant now.

Comment: @ovs True; thanks for your remark.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 34 bytes

Heavily inspired by Jonathan Allan's Jelly solution!

### Encoder: 23 bytes

```
[:*/[:p:[:+/\2|@-~/\0,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/o6209KOtCqyirbT1Y4xqHHTr9GMMdGL/a3IpcKUmZ@QrpAEVGygYwjiGQIjENYBwkTCyLpgosjyMBMH/AA)

```
                    0,]  NB. prepend 0 to the input
             2  -~/\     NB. find the differences
              |@         NB. and their absolute values 
        [:+/\            NB. running sums
    [:p:                 NB. n-th prime
[:*/                     NB. product
```

I don't like those many cap forks `[:` - it should be golfable.

### Decoder: 11 bytes

```
2|[:_1&p:q:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/jWqireIN1QqsCq3@a3IpcKUmZ@QrpCkYGsFYxoamMKaRkbGBpZGFuQFczsLE3MLYxMDI0tTCyMDMyNTI4D8A)

```
        q:    NB. prime factorization
  [:_1&p:      NB. find the number of primes smaller than n
2|             NB. modulo 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 15 bytes

#### Encoder, 9 bytes

```
0;ŒgL€ÆẸH
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/A@uikdJ9HTWsOtz3ctcPj/8Mdm8KAPJBAO5DwBqowMFQwNAQSBjAA5EKBgoEhFCrAGCAxkHKoDggLCEHIwAAA)

#### Decoder, 6 bytes

```
Æf’ÆCḂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW9qjhpmH25wf7mj6/3DHprDD7Y@a1nj//29opGBsaKpgCqQNLc0sjBWMjIwNLI0szA0UjI2MTSxMzMyA0oYWlkAEFLIwMbcwNjEwsjS1MDIwMzI1MgAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 29 + 39 = 68 bytes

### Encoder, 29 bytes

```
021IEh{$:}-Q$TP:SP?!t$|1k*3R!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/38DI0NM1o1rFqlY3UCUkwCo4wF6xRKXGMFvLOEjx/39DLgMuVAwA)

### Decoder, 39 bytes

```
02I:MZ;:2k%:z}Q$TP:SP?!t$|1k,{{-z:N}3R!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/38DI08o3ytrKKFvVqqo2UCUkwCo4wF6xRKXGMFunulq3ysqv1jhI8f9/YyNjEwsTMzNDUwA)

#### How these work

```
Encoder

021IEh{$:}-Q$TP:SP?!t$|1k*3R!

021                            Setup the stack as [last bit, current prime, current output]
   IEh                         Take input as int; if EOF, print top as number and halt
      {$:}-Q          |        If the next bit is different from the last bit...
            $                    Move the prime to the top
             T      t            Loop indefinitely...
              P:SP?!               Increment; if prime, skip `t` i.e. break
                     $           Move the prime to the correct position
                       1k*     Multiply the prime to the output
                          3R!  Skip 3 next commands (the init part)
                               Loop the entire program until EOF

---

Decoder

02I:MZ;:2k%:z}Q$TP:SP?!t$|1k,{{-z:N}3R!

02I                  Setup the stack as [last bit, current prime, encoded]
   :MZ;              If encoded == 1, halt
       :2k%          Compute encoded modulo prime
           :z}       Store NOT of the last at the bottom of the stack
              Q...|  Same as encoder's next-prime loop
1k,                  Divide encoded by prime (assume it is divisible)
   {{                Pull out the two bits at the bottom
     -z              Compute the next bit
       :N}           Print as number with newline, and move to the bottom
          3R!        Skip 3 init commands
                     Loop the entire program until finished
```

It'd be better if I could golf down the next-prime loop...